# Why is “echo $SHELL” not captured by remote SSH output?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, echo, stdout

When I capture the output of a remote SSH call using cat, whether in bash or in Python, things work as expected.

E.g, this works just fine:

```
import subprocess
rc = subprocess.getoutput(“ssh user@host; cat /proc/meminfo”)
print(rc)
>> MemTotal:        2048212 kB
MemFree:          202168 kB
MemAvailable:    1578308 kB
Buffers:          240876 kB
Cached:          1073456 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1049444 kB
…etc
```

However, this yields nothing:

```
import subprocess 
rc = subprocess.getoutput(“ssh user@host; echo $SHELL”)
>>
```

Even though SSHing into the machine as the same user and typing “echo $SHELL” works and outputs to stdout.

What am I missing here?

In my notes I have the following comment:

> If you want to make any local environment variables available for use
> in the shell script, launch the script using the exec command.
>
> Running the script directly from the command prompt spawns a new
> subshell for the script, making any local environment variables in the
> shell not available to the script.

Do I need to use ‘exec’ for these env vars to be made available from a remote command execution?

Please note this not just a Python question or just a RHEL8 question; it is reproducible on other Linux variants as well including Ununtu.

Thanks.

Comment: In which system do you think `cat /proc/meminfo` is being executed when you run `subprocess.getoutput("ssh user@host; cat /proc/meminfo")`?

Comment: This site should help: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases ssh connecton *terminates* and the second command is executed *on the local machine*. E.g. your `/proc/meminfo` output is that of *local* machine and not from a remote in any way.

If you want to run it remotely, use:

`ssh user@host cat /proc/meminfo` — notice *lack* of semicolon, which makes "cat" and "/proc/meminfo" arguments of ssh client, from which it constructs the command line which then runs remotely.

The second case is even more tricky. Not only the semicolon makes it run locally, but the *order of substitution* adds its five cents too.  In naive variant it will substitute a variable locally, and then send a substituted command to the remote to execute. For it to run completely as desired you need to *suppress* the local substitution, for which use single quotes:

`ssh user@host echo '$SHELL'`

(just compare `` ssh user@host echo `hostname -f` ``  and `` ssh user@host echo '`hostname -f`' `` to see what I mean).

---

It seems you are ready to learn [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/getting_started/index.html), because it meant to solve the need to do something over SSH remotely in an automated fashion.